# Need some advice for backup strategy

Tags: backup

I asked some others before but I am still not sure how to solve it exactly.
Basically I have a dev server with multiple folders of different branches for a project. Right now I tar.gz them daily to S3, so I have full daily backups because sometimes a dev comes and asks me to revert to a day before (yea I know...don't tell me). Problem is that this is very IO/Load heavy since we are talking 2 figure gigabytes and 100,000+ files. So now I am asked to backups even more stuff. I thought about rsync but then I miss the daily full option, except maybe combine rsync with "copy changed files to folder, tar it, date name it"? For rsync I'd need a backup server though because S3 as mounted share is super slow and not an option for this amount of files.
What should I do? Or just tell my devs "svn/git do you speak it?"?

thanks for help

Comment: You don't _need_ a daily full backup if you use rsync right.

Comment: "Or just tell my devs 'svn/git do you speak it?'?" Yes, a **thousand times** yes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that you will really benefit from getting a DVCS like git up and running. Have your developers use their own machines and once committed push them to a central server. They can then revert to earlier versions without disturbing you. You can then use rsync to just sync the changes from the server. You could also just pull the repo to a backup server I guess.

Comment: Totally agreeing on this one. A VCS would be greatly beneficial for you if you just incoorporate it correctly into your workflow.

Comment: thanks, I think so too, now I just have to tell them that

Answer (score 0):

rsync is just sync tool - you can sync two locations to have same content. You can look on `rdiff-backup` tool. It transfers diffs from one location to another (as rsync does) but it keeps versions of files on target location, so you can go back in time. If file is not changed, it transfer nothing, just makes note there is no change from last version.